# Insulation and losses In transmission line

Tags: ac, dc, insulation, transmission, line

Why do we consider only
P=V.I
In AC transmission while designing the insulation of transmission line not the equation
P=V^2/Z
and consider this equation in determine the insulation in DC transmission line?

Comment: We don't. Perhaps you'd like to link to where you thought you had seen this, so we could understand your confusion. Insulation is mainly governed by peak voltage, and the environment of the line.

Comment: \$P=V^2/Z\$ is a special case of \$P=VI\$ that is valid when \$I=V/Z\$. When considering transmission lines you must be sure you keep clear exactly what \$V\$ you should be interested in (for example, the voltage between the ends of the line or the voltage across the load).